# Include scroll in a leaderboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a leaderboard here :

The thing is when I click the tabs at the top,the list of persons toggle accordingly.Now I have given only 8 employees here in the leaderboard.

I have 800 employees and I want to include everyone in the list(I will have 4 different list according to the 4 different tabs)  with a scroll bar vertically.also the size of the leaderboard should remain the same,that is why I want a scroll .

can this be possible .Kindly help.

Fiddle link :

```
         [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/sharma1331/xp5qra10/
```

Comment: So you want the size of the leader board to remain the same and in order to navigate the leader board there must be a scroll bar right?

Comment: yeah... exactly @GraveyardQueen

Comment: basically the technique here is putting a fixed `height` and setting the `overlflow-y: auto`, if you don't like the horizontal scroll bar to appear. might as well add `overflow-x: hidden`

Comment: got it @Semi-Friends .Thanks for the input.

Comment: @GraveyardQueen showed me the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code it will work perfectly,

**CSS:**

```
.leaderboard {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  width: 285px;
  height: 200px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a404d, #181c26);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a404d, #181c26);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 30px rgba(62, 9, 11, 0.3);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

You will have to give a fixed height as i have given `height:200px;` and then hide the overflow on the y-axis like this `overflow-x:hidden;` so that the scroll bar will appear if the height is exceeded.

Comment: nope it is overflow-x and not overflow-y run the code in the js-fiddle and check

Comment: Thanks for the input.Works great @GraveyardQueen

Comment: how can I improve the look.If I use what u said,The scroll exceeds the list.Any help would be great. Sry .I knw its too much. @GraveyardQueen

Comment: You should put the same code in the ol class as shown below,
.leaderboard ol {
    counter-reset: leaderboard;
    padding: 0px !important;
    height:200px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}